# SVG fill having issues in Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a CSS property of fill applied on SVG. But that SVG is inside the anchor tag which has a property of color. Everything looks fine in Chrome but when i open the page in Firefox the SVG is taking the color property of the anchor tag to fill the SVG. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

```
<a>
<svg class="icon">
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="icons.svg#icon-tag"></use>
</svg> Special Offers
</a>




a{
color:#somecolor;
}

svg{
fill:#somecolor;
}
```

PS: fill is not getting overridden by color property. And i am fetching the svg from svg sprites file.

Comment: It's a known [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=265894)

Comment: do you know what can be done?

Comment: Sure, download the source code, edit it to fix the bug, add the patch to the bug and I'll review it and get it in the next release. But you didn't mean that did you really?

Comment: Anyways, what i did is i added color property to svg 
svg{fill:#somecolor;
color:#somecolor;
}
This does work, but i am not sure whether it's the accepted way and if i should do this or not.